# How to uncheck a radio button in another radio group?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have two radio groups in one xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the main activity I can handle radio buttons on click listener by implementing the `onRadioButtonClicked()` method:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_1:

            break;
        case R.id.R.id.btn_2: 

            break;
        case R.id.R.id.btn_3: 

            break;
        case R.id.R.id.btn_4: 

            break;
    }
}
```

Now, in the same radio group if a radio button is checked, the other is unchecked automatically. So here is my problem: I want that if a button is checked the other buttons in the same group and in the other group to be unchecked. Is this doable?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually .

```
case R.id.btn_1:
   btn3.setChecked(false);
   btn4.setChecked(false);
  break;
case R.id.btn_2:
   btn3.setChecked(false);
   btn4.setChecked(false);
  break;
case R.id.btn_3:
   btn1.setChecked(false);
   btn2.setChecked(false);
  break;
case R.id.btn_4:
   btn1.setChecked(false);
   btn2.setChecked(false);
  break;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is looks clean but how can i get btn1, btn2, btn3, and btn4 references?

Comment: btn1.setOnCheckedChangeListener()

Comment: you can add the setonCheckedChangeListener on the radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

there is a **clearCheck()** method on RadioGroup.